# How to store custom information to an Outlook AppointmentItem

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am creating an Outlook Add-in that creates new appointments, like so:

```
Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment =
    (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
oAppointment.Subject = subject;
oAppointment.Body = description;
oAppointment.Start = startDate;
oAppointment.End = endDate;
oAppointment.Save();
```

Now, i want to add some custom information to those appointments, so that the application knows which appointments were created by the Add-in. Can I store that information inside the AppointmentItem, or do i have to build some sort of separate data structure that maps the appointment global id to the custom information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using the [UserProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147619%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property for that.